# How to fill the area between two curves (Kaplan Meier)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, survival

How can I fill the area between two curves (Kaplan-Meier) limited to a especific time, in the figure (by example, x=40) where the length of "x" and "y" differ.
x1= km[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI1nV.jpg)$time  y1=km[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI1nV.jpg)$surv  in curve 1; and x2=km[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9dMx.jpg)$time  y2=km[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9dMx.jpg)$surv in curve 2

Thanks

```
library(survival)
data(cancer)
aml

km<- survfit(Surv(time,status)~x, aml)
plot(km, col=1:2)

#x1= km[1]$time  y1=km[1]$surv  in curve 1; and 
#x2= km[2]$time  y2=km[2]$surv  in curve 2
```

[image]

I am looking for something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have tagged with `ggplot2`, so here is a method using `geom_ribbon`. It requires quite a bit of data wrangling to get the model into the correct format though:

```r
library(tidyverse)

with(km, 
  data.frame(time, surv, strata = rep(names(strata), times = strata))
  ) %>%
  mutate(strata = sub("x=", "", strata)) %>%
  group_by(strata) %>%
  summarise(time = c(time - 0.001, time),
            surv = c(1, head(surv, -1), surv),
            .groups = "drop") %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "strata", values_from = "surv") %>%
  fill(2:3, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, Maintained)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = "Maintained")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Nonmaintained, linetype = "Nonmaintained")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Nonmaintained, ymax = Maintained, fill = "Difference"),
              ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, name = "Percentage survival",
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "#6dd8ae", name = NULL) +
  labs(linetype = "Group") +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray95"))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice data wrangling. I'm more used to data.table but always fun to see how things get done the dplyr way.

Answer (score 2):

Probably easier to create a table with the all the `x` observations and fill in the blanks:

```
library(survival)
data(cancer)
km<- survfit(Surv(time,status)~x, aml)


library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(zoo) 

fill_data=function(this_km){
  out=rbind(data.table(time=0,surv=1),data.table(time=this_km$time,surv=this_km$surv))
  out=rbind(na.omit(out[,.(time,surv=shift(surv))]),out)
  setkeyv(out,"time")
  return(out)
}
data=merge(fill_data(km[1]),fill_data(km[2]),by = 'time',all=TRUE,suffixes = c('1','2'))

#Fill in the blanks
data[,surv1:=na.locf(surv1)]
data[,surv2:=na.locf(surv2)]

#plot with geom path and ribbon
ggplot(data =data)+
  geom_ribbon(mapping = aes(x=time,ymin=surv1,ymax=surv2),fill='purple',alpha=.2)+
  geom_path(aes(x=time,y=surv1),col='blue')+
  geom_path(aes(x=time,y=surv2),col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Just saw @allan’s submission. Neat data wrangling indeed!